# Password protected .odt file

Tags: password

I had saved a .odt file with a password,subsequently i uninstalled ubuntu and got windows 7, though i remember the password am not able to open the odt file. Please help as it contains very important data.

Answer (score 2):

Open it with OpenOffice for Windows.

http://www.openoffice.org/download/